# Rewrite Rule in nginx (by-pass) IP

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule as follows:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ https://subdomain.domain.com/abc/xyzdirector/login.do ) {
return    444;
}
```

Now this works fine, however, I want to have an exception to this rule. I want to allow IP A.B.C.D to pass through, i.e. this IP should not be subjected to this rule. How does one do that?

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables has among others the following:

```
$remote_addr
The address of the client. 

$binary_remote_addr
The address of the client in binary form;
```

NOTE:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if indicates the allowed contexts for an if statement as server and location

in other words you can't nest if statements, so you'd get something like the following:

```
location /abc/xyzdirector/login.do { 
  if ( $remote_addr != <allowed adress> ) { return 444;}       
  #if you get here it was an allowed adress so add config to server the request.
}
```